# Use nested Java Class from Kotlin and Inheritance

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the following classes in Java:

```
public class Parent<T>{
    public class Inner {
        private T item;
        //...
    }
    //...
} 

public class Child<T> extends Parent<T> {
    //...
}
```

I now want to use this in the following way in Kotlin:

```
fun handle(test: Child<Something>.Inner) {
    // Error: Unresolved Reverence: Inner
}
```

If I do the same thing in Java, it works:

```
public void handle(Child<Something>.Inner test) {
    //..
}
```

How can I do this in Kotlin?

Comment: `Parent<Something>.Inner` seems to work.

Comment: That is right, but if I wanted to use the parent there I would do so.

Comment: Consider filing an issue on the Kotlin YouTrack with this.

Comment: Can you try something like `fun handle(test: Inner) { ... }` ? `Inner` without `Child<>`.

Comment: @Demigod The whole point for me is to use this with http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/ where the subscribers check on the class that is pushed on the bus, so I do not get subscribed on events I do not want. So if I have Child1<Something> and Child2<Something> I would get both if I am not able to lock it to the one I want. So maybe it would be possible with another typecheck, but having this in every subscriber would be a lot of overhead.

Comment: if it's for event bus i'm surprised a regular inner class works instead of `static class` in java

Comment: @user1892364, so what do you want is to allow to pas `Child1<Something>` but forbid to pass `Child2<Something>`? Despite that in Java you can write something like this `public void handle(Child<Something>.Inner test) { ... }` you also can pass to this methid `Child2<Something>.Inner`.. So it kinda don't locks with the inherited class type.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik issue was filed here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25836

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing static inner class defined in Java, through derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917371/accessing-static-inner-class-defined-in-java-through-derived-class)